# My Xbox freezes when I play Minecraft for a few minutes

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Why does my Xbox freeze when I play in my Minecraft world for about two minutes? The whole Xbox freezes but I can still hear music and in-game sound.

If I take out the game it sends me to the dashboard and it all happens again if retry with the disc. It is not the console because I have also played Skyrim, Far Cry 3 and Thief and none of those crash my Xbox. My hard drive also has 195 GB remaining.

Comment: maybe your disc has scratches, try to install the game to the xbox hdd

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Here is the guide: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/install-play-delete-game#35ec7c0fed9c4079bf85376fec55dad3